# Mixing non-overlapping everygrams in order

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, grammar, n-gram

I'm looking for a method to generate sequences from every-grams up to length `n` that match an input sentence:

Given a sentence:  `"Break this into sequences"`  and `n = 3`

I want to create the sequences:

```
("Break", "this", "into", "sequences")
("Break", "this", "into sequences")
("Break", "this into", "sequences")
("Break this", "into", "sequences")
("Break this", "into sequences")
("Break", "this into sequences")
("Break this into", "sequences")
```

`nltk` has the [`everygram`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.util.html?highlight=everygram#nltk.util.everygrams) package, but I'm not quite sure how I'd use it toward my goal.

I've tried adapting the problem to focus on characters for simplicity, i.e.,

It may be helpful to consider these as character-grams (and, as rici suggested, spacing out characters [with and without spacing shown for clarity]):

`abcd` goes to:

```
(a, b, c, d)       (a, b, c, d)
(a, b, c  d)       (a, b, cd)
(a, b  c, d)       (a, bc, d)
(a  b, c, d)       (ab, c, d)
(a  b, c  d)       (ab, cd)
(a, b  c  d)       (a, bcd)
(a  b  c, d)       (abc, d)
```

For clarity, this should generalize for any length, given a `n` as the maximum-sized n-gram; so, for `abcde` with `n=3` we'd have:

```
(a, b, c, d, e)     (a, b, c, d, e)
(a, b, c, d  e)     (a, b, c, de)
(a, b, c  d, e)     (a, b, cd, e)
(a, b  c, d  e)     (a, bc, d, e)
(a  b, c, d, e)     (ab, c, d, e)
(a, b  c, d  e)     (a, bc, de)
(a  b, c, d  e)     (ab, c, de)
(a  b, c  d, e)     (ab, cd, e)
(a, b, c  d  e)     (a, b, cde)
(a, b  c  d, e)     (a, bcd, e)
(a  b  c, d, e)     (abc, d, e)
(a  b, c  d  e)     (ab, cde)
(a  b  c, d  e)     (abc, de)
```

I'm thinking I may need to generate a grammar, something like:

```
exp ::= ABC, d | a, BCD
ABC ::= AB, c | A, BC
BCD ::= BC, d | b, CD
AB ::= A, b | a, B
BC ::= B, c | b, C
CD ::= C, d | c, D
A ::= a
B ::= b
C ::= c
D ::= d
```

and find all parses of the sentence, but certainly there must be a procedural way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be helpful to space your example out a bit:

```
(a , b , c , d)
(a , b , c   d)
(a , b   c , d)
(a   b , c , d)
(a   b , c   d)
(a , b   c   d)
(a   b   c , d)
(a   b   c   d)  # added for completeness
```

Looking at that, it's evident that what differentiates the rows is the presence or absence of commas, a typical binary choice. There are three places a comma could go, so there are eight possibilities, corresponding to the eight binary numbers of three digits.

The easiest way to list these possibilities is to count from `0 0 0` to `1 1 1`.

---

For your modified question, in which there is a maximum length of a part, one simple recursive solution in Python is:

```py
def kgram(k, v):
    'Generate all partitions of v with parts no larger than k'
    def helper(sfx, m):
        if m == 0: yield sfx
        else:
            for i in range(1, min(k, m)+1):
                yield from helper([v[m-i:m]]+sfx, m-i)

    yield from helper([], len(v))
```

Here's a quick test:

```
>>> for p in gram(3, 'one two three four five'.split()): print(p)
... 
[['one'], ['two'], ['three'], ['four'], ['five']]
[['one', 'two'], ['three'], ['four'], ['five']]
[['one'], ['two', 'three'], ['four'], ['five']]
[['one', 'two', 'three'], ['four'], ['five']]
[['one'], ['two'], ['three', 'four'], ['five']]
[['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four'], ['five']]
[['one'], ['two', 'three', 'four'], ['five']]
[['one'], ['two'], ['three'], ['four', 'five']]
[['one', 'two'], ['three'], ['four', 'five']]
[['one'], ['two', 'three'], ['four', 'five']]
[['one', 'two', 'three'], ['four', 'five']]
[['one'], ['two'], ['three', 'four', 'five']]
[['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four', 'five']]
```

Comment: In this example, you've added a 4-gram; I want to be able to specify some `n` as the maximum n-gram used in the sequences; also, this doesn't generalize, afaik.  Consider e.g., abcde; now there are 4 places for commas, but I'd still only want e.q. n=3-grams in the sequence.

Comment: @randomusername: adding a requirement after you got an answer is a bit provocative. However, the basic idea of selecting a subset of places to put commas certainly generalizes but you need to enumerate combinations.

Comment: ... But since it's late here and I'd have to think about the combinatorics a bit more, I left you with a recursive solution.

Comment: The `n` wasn't added after the fact; thanks for the suggestions, though!